# How to find an integer present in array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am getting result as `true` for the following code

```
var elements1:[Int] = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

if elements1.contains (50) {

    print("true")

}
```

I am having problem finding out what the `if condition` should be for the following to get the result as `true` if `elements2` has 50 in it.

```
var elements2:[[Int]] = [[10], [20, 30], [40, 50]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `joined()` to flatten the nested array in a single one, and apply the `contains` search on the joined array:

```
let elements2 = [[10], [20, 30], [40, 50]]
if elements2.joined().contains(50) {
    print("Contains 50!")
}
```

Note that you needn't include the type annotation for `elements2` above, as the type is inferred (to `[[Int]]`).

Another alternative would be to use `contains` to check each inner array for the `50` element, and proceed if any of the inner arrays contains the value:

```
if elements2.map({ $0.contains(50) }).contains(true) {
    print("Contains 50!")
}
```

Or, using `reduce` to fold the inner arrays to a boolean, checking the possible inclusion of `50` in each inner array (quite similar approach to the one above)

```
if elements2.reduce(false, { $0 || $1.contains(50) }) {
    print("Contains 50!")
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your explanation with alternatives

Comment: @Coder221 happy to help. Added also a `reduce` alternative, but I would personally probably prefer `joined()` (best semantics, imo).

Answer (score 5):

I would probably use `joined` to simplify the task but you can easily use a nested `contains`:

```
var elements2:[[Int]] = [[10], [20, 30], [40, 50]]

if elements2.contains(where: { $0.contains(50) }) {
    print("true")
}
```

Comment: This has the advantage of "short-circuiting".

Comment: what is short-circuiting

Comment: @Coder221 It means that the search stops when the element is found. For example, the `reduce` solution has to iterate all the elements even if the first is the one you want to find.

Comment: Appreciate that, nice to know about it.

Comment: @MartinR would the `map` chained with `contains(true)` (in my answer) also short-circuit (lazily)?

Comment: @dfri I think that `joined` would but I have doubts about `map` without explicitly using `.lazy`.

Comment: @Sulthan yeah I'm also unsure. Thanks!

Comment: @dfri: Sulthan is correct (of course). The Array map() method returns an array, which is fully evaluated before `.contains(true)` is called (which then short-circuits).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary/1687661-flatmap) for that.

```
let newArray = elements2.flatMap { $0 }
if newArray.contains(50) { 
    print("true") 
}
```

Comment: append{$1} also

Comment: newArray is executing 4 times (I have only 3 arrays in the array), even though I am getting desired result.